# Fazer post com api aws

Tags: asp.net-web-api, amazon-aws

Estou tentando fazer um `Post` para um serviço da [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/?nc2=h_lg). 
Nunca trabalhei com AWS e estou estudando alguns links e inincialmente estou a fazer um teste de conexão usando esse código:

```
private static async void SignInUserAsync()
{
    var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1")); 
    try
    {
        string Access_Key = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOO";                
        string Secret_Key = "XXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

        var authReq = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest
        {
            AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH,
            UserPoolId = Access_Key,
            ClientId = Secret_Key
        };

        AdminInitiateAuthResponse authResp = await provider.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(authReq);

        if (authResp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Autenticação ok!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("falhou!");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Instalei o SDK:

[AWS SDK para .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-net/)

As seguintes extensões no VS2017: 
[AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2017)

A dúvida é que não consigo fazer a autenticação com o AWS  pois retorna o erro 400, a chave e o código de acesso foi enviado pelo cliente: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: alguns pontos me chamaram atenção: Você está tentando fazer uma autenticação de Administrador utilizando credenciais anônimas? Você já tentou com criar chaves e utlizar? outro material para sua referência: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/mobile/use-csharp-to-register-and-authenticate-with-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Comment: Adrianojc você poderia esclarecer se é apenas o AmazonCognito que gostaria de interagir? Sendo assim quando comenta que quer "Fazer um post em um serviço" seria um requisição no AmazonCognito?

Answer (score 0):

Cara poderia tentar utilizar esse metodo para autenticar ? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client__ctor_9.htm

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();

    _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
        "00000000000000000000", //ID_Access
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", //Key_Access
        config
    );
```

Aqui se encontra toda documentação da AWS que está me ajudando muito até então

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client.htm

Comment: parece que o adrianojc quer autenticar no Amazon Cognito e não em um S3 diretamente, mas entendo que o Cognito pode ser um método de autenticação para o S3. Imagino que sua resposta não endereça a pergunta feita.